Error Invalid hook call Next 14
estoy obteniendo este error alguien podira ayudarme a soluciononarlo estoy usando Next14.

Obtengo este error al utilizar esta función, alguien puede guiarme a solucionarlo por favor, no encuentro el error, porque no parace ser ninguna de las 3 indicaciones que nombre el error. el código es el siguiente:
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { useSession, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
    
    export function Fetch(url, method, body, withSession) {
    
      const [payload, setPayload] = useState([]);
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    
      useEffect(() => {
        try {
          fetch(
            `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}${url}/${
              withSession && status != "loading" && session.user.id
            }`
          )
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then(async (data) => {
              if (data.message === "unauthorized") {
                await signOut({ callbackUrl: "/" });
              }
              setPayload(data);
              setLoading(false);
            });
        } catch (e) {
          setLoading(false);
          return console.log("err try fetch: ", e);
        }
      }, [status]);
    
      if (isLoading) return isLoading;
      if (payload) return payload;
    
      return { data: [], msg: "Error en la petición" };
    }


Hace falta informacíon para poder depurar, hay que agregar el código del componente que esta llamando a Fetch
